# Meaning of "upon 90 days"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, legalese

In a license contract we have, this legalenglish quote:

> LICENSEE reserves the right to terminate this License Agreement with or without cause upon 90 days written notice for LICENSOR beyond the three year term.

I am struggling to find the meaning of "upon 90 days written notice". Does this mean LICENSEE needs to inform LICENSOR about the termination of the contract 90 days before it happens?

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the sentence:

> We can terminate this Agreement upon 90 days notice

"Upon" in this sentence is [used to say that something has arrived](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upon).

So, when 90 days notice has been given, the agreement can be terminated.

You are correct in your understanding that the termination will happen 90 days after you give notice.